# Dynamically load different XML files to Hive tables

Tags: java, xml, hive

I have a folder/stream of different complex XML files (each of size ~ 1GB). I know how to load an XMLfile data to Hive table (or any Hadoop data base).
But I want to know two things:

1. Can I load each xml file data to hive **dynamically**, i.e. without explicitly writing a **create table** command (because I get different XML files as a stream), is there any way which does this automatically.

"Stream of different complex xml Files --> Load to Hive tables (with out manually writing Create table command) --> Use the data which is loaded into Hive tables"

2. Instead of writing command line scripts to create hive tables, How can I write a java code to load xml data to Hive table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, AFAIK, it is not possible. Hive is intended to manage data that is stored *within* Hive tables (it is not always stored within tables, but metadata is added to the tables, *pointing* to the real data, that's the case of Hive external tables).

The only thing I think you can try is to create a single big table for all the data within your XML files, the already stored ones and the future ones; the trick is to put all the XML files under a common HDFS folder that it is used as the location of the `create table` command.

Regarding your second question, please refer to this code:

```
public final class HiveBasicClient {

    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    private static Connection con;

    private static Connection getConnection(String hiveServer, String hivePort, String hadoopUser, String hadoopPassword) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://" + hiveServer + ":" + hivePort + "/default?user=" + hadoopUser + "&password=" + hadoopPassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return null;
        } 
    }

    private static res doQuery(String query) {
        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            res.close();
            stmt.close();
            return res;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hiveServer = args[0];
        String hivePort = args[1];
        String hadoopUser = args[2];
        String hadoopPassword = args[3];

        con = getConnection(hiveServer, hivePort, hadoopUser, hadoopPassword);
        doQuery("create external table <table_name> (<list_of_columns>) row format serde '<your_xml_serde>' location `<your_xml_files_location>');
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Will check on what you've posted.